# How to verify an imported GPG key

Tags: gpg

I'm new to this PGP thing.  Here are my questions:
**Verification**
When I do this, I'm given the message "This key is not certified with a trusted signature".  Is there anyway to make it trusted and better yet what's the proper way for doing so?

```
[root@dev /]# gpg --verify bind-9.9.4-P2.tar.gz.sha512.asc bind-9.9.4-P2.copiedlink.tar.gz
gpg: Signature made Fri 03 Jan 2014 01:58:50 PM PST using RSA key ID 189CDBC5
gpg: Good signature from "Internet Systems Consortium, Inc. (Signing key, 2013) <codesign@isc.org>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 2B48 A38A E1CF 9886 435F  89EE 45AC 7857 189C DBC5
```

**Managing Key**
I downloaded and saved a public key as isc.public.key, and imported it using the following command:

```
gpg –import isc.public.key
```

I'm sure there is an expiration date on it so how do I do the following:

1. Find out when it expires?  In fact does GPG tells me when the key I've imported has already expired when I do a "gpg --verify"?
2. Update the key.  Do I have to delete the key and re-import when this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: As larsks said, good security is hard; and this is a little flip in response to a sincere question with reasonable detail, no? If I'm wrong I'm sure to recieve a smackdown, and I can't afford any loss of "status" with my total standing at 118 ;-} That said I'm voting you up for the 'web of trust' search term suggestion.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> When I do this, I'm given the message "This key is not certified with a trusted signature". Is there anyway to make it trusted and better yet what's the proper way for doing so?

A "trusted signature" is a signature from a key that you trust, either because (a) you have personally verified that it belongs to the person to whom it claims to belong, or (b) because it has been signed by a key that you trust, possibly through a series of intermediate keys.

You can edit the trust level of keys by running "gpg --edit-key ", and then using the `trust` command.  [This section](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html) of the GPG manual discusses key trust, and it's worth a read: good security is hard.

Note that the warning "This key is not certified with a trusted signature" basically means, "this thing could have been signed by anybody".  I can create a key that claims to be for "Internet Systems Consortium, Inc. (Signing key, 2013) ", and sign things with it, and GPG will happily confirm that yes, the things I signed were signed with my key.  To avoid this problem, you would presumably download the ISC GPG key from [the website](https://www.isc.org/downloads/software-support-policy/openpgp-key/) and either trust it ultimately ("I believe this entity can certify itself") or sign it with your ultimately-trusted private key.  Without proper management of key trust, signature verification is mostly theater.

> Find out when it expires?

Running `gpg -k <keyid>` will show you when a given key expires.  For example, I created a key that expires tomorrow, and `gpg -k <keyid>` gives me:

```
$ gpg -k 0xD4C2B757C3FAE256
pub   2048R/0xD4C2B757C3FAE256 2014-01-26 [expires: 2014-01-27]
uid                 [ultimate] Test User <testuser@example.com>
sub   2048R/0xE87A56CDCC670D7A 2014-01-26 [expires: 2014-01-27]
```

You can see that the expiration dates on subkeys are clearly marked.  Note that subkeys used for signing and encryption may have different expiration dates from the primary key.  You can read more about subkeys [here](https://wiki.debian.org/subkeys).

> In fact does GPG tells me when the key I've imported has already expired when I do a "gpg --verify"?

Yes, GPG will notify you about an expired key.  Note that this does not necessarily represent a problem: the signature was valid when the document was signed.

> Update the key. Do I have to delete the key and re-import when this happens?

You should have you GPG environment configured to use a keyserver, and periodically run `gpg --refresh-keys`.  This will update any keys in your keyring with new information from the keyserver, which may include:

- new expiration dates
- additional signatures on the key

If a person or organization begins using a new key, you would just add it to your keychain -- you would not need to delete the existing key.

Comment: What if there is no expiration field?

Comment: See also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69062/what-is-the-difference-between-full-and-ultimate-trust

Answer (score 1):

If we import the public key of the person who made a signature for a file and we just tried to verify the signature of that file with:

```
gpg --verify some-download.zip.asc some-download.zip
```

and saw a warning like:

```
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
```

it likely means we haven't ***signed*** the public key of the signature-maker.  **Signing someone else's public key is GPG's way to indicate we think the key is accurate, authentic, valid**.  (There is also a "web of trust" that can avoid this warning situation, but that's very likely not your issue/situation.)

### The Fix

To ***sign/certify/validate*** that signer's key ***after*** we have imported their public key and ***after*** we've set **trust** on their key (some value between none, marginal, fully, ultimate) we need to:

```
gpg --lsign-key <signers-pubkey-ID>
```

This is us using **our private GPG key** to personally **sign and CERTIFY** that **we** trust/validate/vouch/certify/solemnly-swear-as-legit this signer's key and the signatures they make with their key belong to the person named/identified by the key.

If there are multiple emails/identities associated with the signer's public key we'll be asked:

```
Really sign all user ID's? (y/N)
```

Answer `y` and hit return.

We'll be asked: `Really sign? (y/N)`.

Answer `y` and hit return.

The above `--lsign-key` is to sign/vouch for a public key **only locally** on our own machine.  If we want to do so publicly and upload our vouching to a keyserver we can use `--sign-key`.

## Notes / Thoughts

When we `--lsign-key` / `--sign-key`, we should be very sure that that key belongs to the person we think it belongs to / is listed as the owner.  It's us putting our personal rubber-stamp on that key as being legit & owned by the person listed.

No one should be able to fake our certification/validation when we *sign* someone else's public key, because we were required to use our **private key** to **certify/validate**.  A private key should (hopefully) be only accessible to the owner and (hopefully) password protected and therefore cannot be faked and thus we have personally vouched for this other person's public key & signatures produced from that key.

#### "trust" vs "validity"

The editing of "trust" (setting it from none to ultimate) using `gpg --edit-key <some-key-ID>` then setting **trust** from 0 to 5 **isn't about how much we trust that key**.  That **trust** is how much we trust the owner of that key to **vouch for others and their keys** (creating a "web of trust").

It's unfortunate that the wording around **trust** and **validity** in GPG documentation/commands is confusing.  It's confusing when we set "trust" of a public key and yet it doesn't affect **our** trust of that exact key, but rather, how much we value (trust) that person's validation of yet other keys.

When we set "trust" in GPG, we (in our own heads) say:

"I (Billy) trust Jane ultimately."

GPG interprets that as:

"Billy trusts Jane to the ultimate degree to ***vouch*** for GPG keys that ***she herself*** has signed as valid."

When what we really wanted GPG to hear was:

"I (Billy) ultimately trust this key is Jane's key."

To get GPG to understand that, we need to:

`--sign-key` or `--lsign-key` Jane's public key, not `trust` her.

## Example

#### Freshly Imported Key

Import the public key of Other User.

```
$ gpg --import OtherU_pubkey.asc
gpg: key 70E670E670E670E6: public key "Other User (https://somesite.org) <other@user.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

If we edit the key now, it will have no trust, no validity:

```
$ gpg --edit-key 70E670E670E670E6

pub  rsa4096/70E670E670E670E6
     created: 2011-06-15  expires: never       usage: SC
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
sub  rsa4096/CD84CD84CD84CD84
     created: 2011-06-15  expires: never       usage: E
[ unknown] (1). Other User (https://somesite.org) <other@user.org>
[ unknown] (2)  OtherU <other@gmail.com>
[ unknown] (3)  Other User <other@gmail.com>
```

Notice three things: `trust: unknown` and `validity: unknown` and `[ unknown ]`.

#### Trust ≠ Validity

If we set `trust` to `4`, the key will show `trust: full` but `validity` will remain `unknown`.

```
gpg> trust
pub  rsa4096/70E670E670E670E6
     created: 2011-06-15  expires: never       usage: SC
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
sub  rsa4096/CD84CD84CD84CD84
     created: 2011-06-15  expires: never       usage: E
[ unknown] (1). Other User (https://somesite.org) <other@user.org>
[ unknown] (2)  OtherU <other@gmail.com>
[ unknown] (3)  Other User <other@gmail.com>

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision? 4

pub  rsa4096/70E670E670E670E6
     created: 2011-06-15  expires: never       usage: SC
     trust: full          validity: unknown
sub  rsa4096/CD84CD84CD84CD84
     created: 2011-06-15  expires: never       usage: E
[ unknown] (1). Other User (https://somesite.org) <other@user.org>
[ unknown] (2)  OtherU <other@gmail.com>
[ unknown] (3)  Other User <other@gmail.com>
Please note that the shown key validity is not necessarily correct
unless you restart the program.
```

Note that the key now reads `trust: full` `validity: unknown`.   That `validity: unknown` is what is causing the WARNING in the question.

The `[ unknown]`s also indicate we haven't validated the key / its associated user IDs (identified by names, emails, websites, etc.).

If we `sign` (or `lsign` i.e. local sign) the key, its validity will go `full`:

```
gpg> lsign
Really sign all user IDs? (y/N) y

pub  rsa4096/70E670E670E670E6
     created: 2011-06-15  expires: never       usage: SC
     trust: full          validity: unknown
 Primary key fingerprint: 70E6 70E6 70E6 EE56 31BE  D950 70E6 70E6 70E6 70E6

     Other User (https://somesite.org) <other@user.org>
     OtherU <other@gmail.com>
     Other User <other@gmail.com>

Are you sure that you want to sign this key with your
key "Me MyKey <me@superuser.com>" (L0LCAT5HA58URG3R)

The signature will be marked as non-exportable.

Really sign? (y/N) y

gpg> save
```

Remember to `save` which will also quit you out of GPG.

If you edit the key again:

```
$ gpg --edit-key 70E670E670E670E6

pub  rsa4096/70E670E670E670E6
     created: 2011-06-15  expires: never       usage: SC
     trust: full          validity: full
sub  rsa4096/CD84CD84CD84CD84
     created: 2011-06-15  expires: never       usage: E
[  full  ] (1). Other User (https://somesite.org) <other@user.org>
[  full  ] (2)  OtherU <other@gmail.come>
[  full  ] (3)  Other User <other@gmail.com>
```

we'll see `trust: full` and `validity: full`.
Also the square brackets before the user IDs are now all `[ full ]`.

When we now check signatures for this public key, we'll not see warnings of certification/validity.  (If the file was signed by multiple keys, you will see warnings of `Can't check signature: No public key` for those other signers.)

```
$ gpg --verify some-download.zip.asc some-download.zip

gpg: Signature made Thu 17 Aug 12:09:32 2023 PDT
gpg:                using RSA key 70E670E670E6EE5631BED95070E670E670E670E6
gpg: Good signature from "Other User (https://somesite.org) <other@user.org>" [full]
gpg:                 aka "OtherU <other@gmail.com>" [full]
gpg:                 aka "Other User <other@gmail.com>" [full]
```